# Github Super linter - Typescript Standard linting broken

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk, super-linter

I upgraded Super Linter from version 4.9.0 to version 5.0.0. Since then the TS Standard Linting fails. On each file it processes it prints the following error message:

```
------
ts-standard: Standard for TypeScript! (https://github.com/standard/ts-standard)
  /tmp/lint/bin/super-linter-ts-trouble.ts:0:0: Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `<tsconfigRootDir>/bin/super-linter-ts-trouble.ts` using `parserOptions.project`: /action/lib/.automation/tsconfig.json
However, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:
- Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file
- Change that TSConfig to include this file
- Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your parserOptions.project
See the typescript-eslint docs for more info: https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting#i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-file (null)
------
```

The hints on the referred url don't work for me. Error can be reproduced with the following steps:

```
git init
cdk init app --language=typescript
git add -A
git commit -m 'initial commit'
docker run -e RUN_LOCAL=true -e VALIDATE_TYPESCRIPT_STANDARD=true -v .:/tmp/lint github/super-linter:v5.0.0
```

If you run the linter 4.9.0, it complains, but the files are processed anyway:

```
docker run -e RUN_LOCAL=true -e VALIDATE_TYPESCRIPT_STANDARD=true -v .:/tmp/lint github/super-linter:v4.9.0
```

Do you have any idea or even a solution for this problem? Thanks in advance